# Uniform limit of injective analytic functions is injective

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on the following problem:

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of injective analytic functions on the unit disc $D$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of $D$.  Show that $f$ is either injective or constant.

Already $f$ is analytic as an almost uniform limit.  If $f'$ is identically zero, then $f$ is constant.  Otherwise $f'$ has isolated zeroes.  If $c$ is such an isolated zero, then $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on a small disc near $c$.  By Hurwitz's theorem, for almost all $n$ the functions $f_n'$ should also have a zero in that small disc.

But an analytic function is locally injective at a point if and only if its derivative at the point is nonzero.  And injective implies locally injective.  So the $f_n'$ shouldn't have any zeros in $D$.

So, we can at least conclude that $f'$ is never zero on $D$.  This shows that $f$ is locally injective.  Is there an easy way to conclude injectivity from local injectivity here?

Comment: Great explanation of your progress so far, by the way!

Comment: Idea: use the argument principle to write down a contour integral that equals the number of times that $f(z)=0$ (and, easy generalization, $f(z)=c$; compare to the analogous contour integrals for the $f_n$. Alternately, use Rouché's theorem for similar contour integrals.

Comment: @D_S: note that a holomorphic function $h: D \to D$ that is locally injective is not necessarily injective. if you take $h(z)=e^{-4\pi} e^{4\pi z}$, then $h(D) \subset D$ and $h$ is locally injective, but $h(0)=h(i/2)$. it would be true however if you were to know eg that $f$ is proper

Comment: I don't see an easy way to conclude injectivity from the local injectivity. The only ways I could think of are badly concealed versions of the direct proof of injectivity via Hurwitz's theorem. (Suppose $f$ were neither constant nor injective. Let $f(z_1) = w = f(z_2)$ for $z_1 \neq z_2$. Take two disjoint small disks $D_k$ around $z_k$, such that $f(z) \neq w$ on $\partial D_k$. By Hurwitz, $f_n$ attains the value $w$ in $D_1$ and in $D_2$ for large enough $n$, contradicting the assumed injectivity of $f_n$.)

Comment: Any reason you did not accept the posted answer?

Comment: It was posted 3 years after I asked the question and I forgot about it : P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uniform limit of injective analytic functions is injective, if this limit IS NOT CONSTANT.

Proof. Suppose that $f(z)=a$ at two points $z_1,z_2$. Surround these two points by a Jordan curve $\gamma$ such that $f(z)\neq a$  on $\gamma$. Then according to the argument principle
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\frac{f'(z)dz}{f(z)-a}\geq 2.$$
(The right hand side equals to the number of solutions of $f(z)=a$ inside $\gamma$,
counting multiplicity). On the other hand, $f_n(z)\neq a$ on $\gamma$ when $n$ is sufficiently large, and the similar integral with $f_n$ instead of $f$ is
$\leq 1$, because $f_n$ are injective. But this is a contradiction because
$f_n\to f$ uniformly, so integral with $f_n$ must converge to the integral with $f$.